# Dealing with circular relationships in JPA

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I'm developing a REST API in JavaEE for an app dealing with managing room reservations.
I've got the following problem:

My app has 3 entity classes:

```java
@Entity
public class Reservation {

    @GeneratedValue
    @Id
    private Integer id;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="room_id")
    private Room room;
    private LocalDateTime reservationStart;
    private LocalDateTime reservationEnd;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="user_id")
    private User user;
```

```java
@Entity
public class Room {
    @GeneratedValue
    @Id
    private Integer id;
    private String description;
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "room")
    private List<Reservation> reservations;
}
```

```java
@Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;
    private String firstName;
    private String surname;
    private UserRole role;
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "user")
    private List<Reservation> reservations;
}
```

I want to, in one query in DAO using JPA, retrieve all the data belonging to a user:
personal data, user's reservations, and the room details for each reservation,
without creating an infinite amount of nested objects:

```json
{
  "user": {
    "id": "id",
    "firstname": "name",
    "lastname": "lastname",
    "email": "email",
    "Reservations": [
      {
      "id" : "1234",
      "startdate": "S",
      "stopdate": "date",
      "room": {
        "id": "id",
        "description": "somedescription"
      }
    },
    {
      "id" : "2134",
      "startdate": "S",
      "stopdate": "date",
      "room": {
        "id": "id",
        "description": "description"
      }
    }
    ]
  }
}
```

Naive approach:

```java
    public User read(Integer id) {
        return entityManager.find(User.class, id);
    }
```

Obviously returns LazyInitializationError, Reservations are returned as PersistentBag, not as List, because they are not initiated.

```java
    public User read(Integer id) {
        User user = entityManager.find(User.class, id);
        user.getReservations();
        return user;
    }
```

Returns the same.

So does:

```java
    public User read(Integer id) {
        Query query = entityManager.createQuery("select u from User u " +
                "join fetch u.reservations r " +
                "where u.id = :id");
        query.setParameter("id", id);
        Object singleResult = query.getSingleResult();
        return (User) singleResult;
    }
```

Switching to FetchType.Eager ends in RESTEASY008205: JSON Binding serialization error java.lang.StackOverflowError, I assume because yasson tries to do infinitely deeply nested JSONs.

I don't want to use @JsonbTransient annotations on @ManyToOne relations, because I also want to be able to retrieve, for example, all reservations belonging to a room, say filtered by date, and within those reservations the information who reserved them, so I will need these fields.

I can retrieve the data (at the console) with a simple SQL query:

```sql
select * from User
         LEFT JOIN Reservation as reservation on user_id = reservation.user_id
         LEFT JOIN Room as room on reservation.room_id = room.id
WHERE User_id = 1
```

but  entityManager.createNativeQuery returns

```
NonUniqueDiscoveredSqlAliasException: Encountered a duplicated sql alias [id] during auto-discovery of a native-sql query
```

JAX-RS endpoint is marked as Transactional. It has a directly injected DAO object which in return has an injected EntityManager.
I'm using JBOSS 20.0.1FINAL, Hibernate 5.4.9, JAVAEE 8.0.1, Java 1.8.

Probably it's just a matter of one good query in JPQL, but as of now I've spend over 2 days on it, and still can't get it to work (but learned plenty about debugging Hibernate), so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Usually this is solved by introducing DTOs and I think this is a perfect use case for [Blaze-Persistence Entity Views](https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence#entity-view-usage).

I created the library to allow easy mapping between JPA models and custom interface or abstract class defined models, something like Spring Data Projections on steroids. The idea is that you define your target structure(domain model) the way you like and map attributes(getters) via JPQL expressions to the entity model.

A DTO model for your use case could look like the following with Blaze-Persistence Entity-Views:

```
@EntityView(User.class)
public interface UserDto {
    @IdMapping
    Integer getId();
    String getFirstname();
    String getLastname();
    String getEmail();
    Set<ReservationDto> getReservations();

    @EntityView(Reservation.class)
    interface ReservationDto {
        @IdMapping
        Integer getId();
        @Mapping("reservationStart")
        LocalDateTime getStartdate();
        @Mapping("reservationEnd")
        LocalDateTime getEnddate();
        RoomDto getRoom();
    }
    @EntityView(Room.class)
    interface RoomDto {
        @IdMapping
        Integer getId();
        String getDescription();
    }
}
```

Querying is a matter of applying the entity view to a query, the simplest being just a query by id.

`UserDto a = entityViewManager.find(entityManager, UserDto.class, id);`

The Spring Data integration allows you to use it almost like Spring Data Projections: https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/entity-view/manual/en_US/index.html#spring-data-features

```
Page<UserDto> findAll(Pageable pageable);
```

The best part is, it will only fetch the state that is actually necessary!

Comment: This absolutely makes sense, I went for manual DTO though, and was able to finally get it to work. Having said that I will take a look into either Spring Data or your library. This definitely should be automated instead of having to manually handle all getters, setters, and looping trough nested collections.